# Triple integral of $f(x,y,z)=yz$ bounded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the coordinate planes $(x,y,z)$ and by the plane $x+y+2z=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

The Region R in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded by the three coordinate planes of a Cartesian coordinate system $(x,y,z)$ and by the plane defined by the equation $x+y+2z=1$. Evaluate the integral $ \int_{R}^{} f \,dV = \int_{R}^{} f \,d(x,y,z)$ when $f(x,y,z)=yz$.

My first step was to find the boundaries of the required triple integral. The lower boundary for $x,y,z$ is always $0$ and the upper boundaries are: for $x$ is $1$, for $y$ it is $1-x$ and for $z$ it is $(1-x-y)/2$. So I arrive to the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{1}  \, \int_{0}^{1-x}  \, \int_{0}^{(1-x-y)/2} yz \,dzdydx$. After calculations, I end with the integral $(1/96) \int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^4 \,dx$ which is equal with $1/480$.

I know for certain that my integral calculations are correct and indeed this is the result for this particular triple Integral. My question is this: are my boundaries for $x,y,z$ correct?

Comment: I think the bounds are correct, but the dx and dy should go after the dz in the triple integral.

Comment: @person I usually write it $dzdydx$ as well but was influenced by my advanced calc book from university (published in the 80s)